# MEAN Stack Node Js with SQL Database - fetch Datatable and read it on the browser local host

Tags: sql, node.js, database, mean-stack

I am building an App with MEAN Stack and would like to integrate a SQL database, in particular fetching datatables and reading them on the browser local host.

So far, Im able to read any datatable with the following code. However, this code just console logs the data tables in the terminal, but I would like to read them in  the browser. Any suggestions?

```
var Connection = require("tedious").Connection;
var Request = require("tedious").Request;

// Create connection to database
var config = {
  userName: "insert username",
  password: "insert password",
  server: "insert server",
  options: {
    database: "insert database name",
    encrypt: true
  }
};
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on("connect", function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Connected to SQL database!");
    queryDatabase();
  }
});

function queryDatabase() {
  console.log("Reading rows from the Table...");

  // Read all rows from table
  request = new Request("SELECT * from <insert name of existing datatable from database", function(
    err,
    rowCount,
    rows
  ) {
    console.log(rowCount + " row(s) returned");
    process.exit();
  });

  request.on("row", function(columns) {
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, column.value);
    });
  });
  connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a [response](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) object, you could collect the column data that you currently log to the console in an array instead, and then send that array to the browser encoded as a JSON string.

```
request.on("row", function(columns) {
    var output = [];
    columns.forEach(function(column) {
      output.push("{0}\t{1}".format(column.metadata.colName, column.value));
    });
     response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
     response.write(JSON.stringify(output))
     response.end();
  });
```

On all browsers except firefox, the JSON is shown as plain text by default. To view it as a tree structure in Chrome you can go to developer tools->network, reload the page, then click the result->preview to view it as a collapsable tree structure. Otherwise i'd advise you install a plugin to enable viewing parsed JSON. For chrome, i strongly recommend the [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa/related) plugin. I don't have useful advice for other browsers but you can google for those.

see

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse
- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa/related

Comment: Hi Jordy, thanks for your reply. Your code does not work but instead it hangs on "Reading rows from the table". What can it be?

Comment: Do you actually have a response object defined? these usually come from a .createServer() or .use() function, see this tutorial for an example:
https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/.
You need this response object to be able to send anything back to the browser. Without it, your program would error out and hang without results.

Comment: Hi J141, thanks for your reply. Would you mind writing down the code I need? Your link is quite hard to follow because it does not reflect my specific case. Many thanks, GB

Comment: Hello GB86,
If i'm to write down a concrete example for you, i need more code. Could you also include a snippet of the code that handles incoming requests on the server? please edit the original post.